# What is difference between data type Variable vs VariableV2?

Tags: variables, tensorflow

In tensorflow, I saw several types of nodes. However I am not sure about distinguish between Variable and VariableV2.
I am very thankful if give some specific difference between two types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py#L96), `tf.variable_op` (which corresponds to `Variable` type) is deprecated:

> Deprecated. Used `variable_op_v2` instead.

So one is the new version of the other. Right now, both are supported, but in the future versions `Variable` is likely to be dropped.

Comment: So you mean that Variable type is not used in tensorflow anymore?

Comment: I haven't seen any usages in 1.5, but I can't be completely sure of that. `Variable` class is using v2 op

Comment: Oh.. However I actually see the version 1.3, there exists two types both. Is there any other meanings in Variable and VariableV2?

Comment: In terms of API, `variable_op`  has a `set_shape` argument, which is gone in `variable_op_v2`, and it looks like getting rid of it was the main motivation for another op. In terms of functionality, it's the same - that's the op that owns the memory for the variable, so that other ops can read or write it.

Comment: Very thankful!! Now I can understand with two types.